# I want to automate a python function with a list of variables

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys

print('Do you want a cup of tea?')

user_input_tea = input().lower()

if user_input_tea == 'yes':
    print("You feel the thirst for a nice cup of tea, now it's time to make it.")
else:
    print('You feel a cup of tea is not for you.')
    sys.exit(0)

equipment = []

def equipment_find(item):
    if item == str(item):
        print("You have acquired the " + str(item) + " , now it's time to proceed.")
        equipment.append(item)
        print(equipment)
    else:
        print("You did not enter: " + str(item))

        while True:
            print("Please input: " str(item))
            if item == str(item):
                equipment.append(item)
                print(equipment)
                break

print("You are going to need a kettle for this tea making process, please input kettle to acquire the kettle")

kettle = input().lower()

equipment_find(kettle)
```

The code above is what I have. I want it so I have the variables with user input already made, is there anyway i could automate the function to trigger with a for loop or something.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? You want to make testing easier so you don't have to input manually?  If you simply want to avoid user input, just replace your input statements with actual strings. So for example ``user_input_tea = 'yes'`` and so on.

Comment: I want to have user input, and will create more variables, i just want it too loop so i don't have to keep typing equipment_find(variable) every time, and have it loop through all the given variables until all the variables are covered and then i'll have the code move on, of which it will go into another fucntion i'll write in later. 

i thought of adding a list or dictionary with all the variables in instead and then have a for loop go through the list and trigger the function for each variable in the list but i wouldn't know how to go about this.

i am new to coding btw

Comment: Dictionary would work well if you want to support morer then just tea. So you can do something like: ``recipesDict = {'tea': ['kettle', 'water', 'spoon', 'sugar'], 'cereal': ['milk', 'flakes', 'bowl']}``

Comment: If you are looking to learn foundation of python properly, check out this tutorial, it is really really good: [Hands-on Python Tutorial](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example of what I think you are looking to accomplish. We specify a list of required ingredients and ask user to enter items until they have all of them. I am using [set()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) during comparison as we don't care about order in which the items were entered.

```
requiredItemsList = ['kettle', 'water', 'spoon', 'sugar']
enteredItmesList = []

print("You feel the thirst for a nice cup of tea, now it's time to make it.")

while set(requiredItemsList) != set(enteredItmesList):
    item = input('Enter an item: ')
    if item in requiredItemsList and item not in enteredItmesList:
        print('You have acquired the', item, ", now it's time to proceed.")
        enteredItmesList.append(item)
    else:
        print('The item you entered is not valid. Please try again.')

print('You have aquired all needed items!')
print(enteredItmesList)
```